# Sorting a column of values into a formatted sheet for printing labels

Tags: excel, vba

So I have to print about 4,000 labels for work. I have a complete list on excel of what every needs to say, and I made a template on another sheet for the labels to be printed on. Where it gets a bit tricky, is that because of the way the labels are formatted on the page, I only want to paste values into every other column and every third row.

My plan was to have a function that returns the next empty cell, then to use a for each loop to copy each value from the master list into the formatted sheet, using the nextCell function to determine which cell to place it in. I have not gotten to the for each loop yet, but that should be the easy part. Below is my nextCell function however which is not working right. It exits the function immediately after the first for every time I run it line by line. I was testing it with some text in the first few target cells so it should not exit immediately.

```
Function nextCell() As Range
 Dim i As Long, j As Long, ws As Worksheet, lbls As Worksheet
 Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
 Set lbls = Worksheets("Sheet2")
 Static n As Long
 If n = 0 Then
  n = 1
 End If
 j = 1
  For i = n To i = 630 Step 3
    For j = 1 To j = 35 Step 2
     If ws.Cells(i, j).Value = 0 Or _
      ws.Cells(i, j).Value = "" Then
      nextCell = ws.Cells(i, j)
      n = i
      Exit Function
   End If
  Next j
Next i
End Function
```

Comment: For one thing your syntax is off. It should be `For i = n To 630 Step 3`.

Comment: Why do you exit as soon as the condition is satisfied - why are you using a function rather than a sub?

Comment: Can you not just use `Offset`? Also, have you considered a **Mail Merge**?.. Also, you don't need to set `j = 1` as **j** is used in your `FOR` loop where you set the initial value for **j** anyway

Comment: gotcha thank you all for your advice! I will try those things, I can offset but its formatted sheets so when it gets to some cell it needs to stop, go down three rows and start again at the first column. I am using a function for this so that I can then use a for each loop in a main sub to copy every value in the range I have set with the data to be sorted over into the formatted sheet. Open to suggestions on anything including the basis of the way I am doing it

Comment: I had hoped exiting once the condition is satisfied would just return a cell, then in the for each loop I can tell it to copy the target cell from data list and paste it into the next empty cell returned by this function

Comment: I am not familiar with Mail Merges but am looking into them @Zac